# Route networktraffic target dependent to different networkadapters

Tags: windows, linux, networking, home-networking, routing

is it possible (Ubuntu and Windows) to create the following rules:

`If target="192.168.*" use eth0`
`If target="*" use eht1 // default, the rest that doesn't match another rule`

Comment: For ubuntu see here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html#ip-masquerading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If target="192.168.*" use eth0

Read up on [subnetting](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work) and the route command. It is designed for this. Specifically, use the *route add* command.

> If target="*" use eht1 // default, the rest that doesn't match another rule

That is done by putting the default gateway via eth1.

This is basic TCP/IP networking, and is the same on both windows and GNU/Linux.